# Subsemigroups of finite semigroup

Tags: semigroups, finite-semigroups

Let S be finite semigroup and let the set $K^{e}=${$a\in S: a^{p}=e ~{~\rm for~some} \quad  p>0$}~ be a subsemigroup of $S$ corresponding to the idempotent $e\in S$. Moreover, let $S$ be the disjoint union of all $K^{e_i}$ for $e_i$ in $E(S)$.

Generally, the condition that $a\in K^{e_i}\setminus (K^{e_i})^{2}$  does not necessarily hold true for  $a\in S\setminus S^{2}$?  Are there any prerequisites that must be met to verify this implication?

Comment: Why is $K^e$ a subsemigroup?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I know there are several examples such that $K^{e}$ is not a subsemigroup.  This was my assumption because it may be applicable to my research topic.